# VBA - Simple recursive function query

Tags: string, vba, function, recursion, replace

I almost feel embarrassed asking this but i have spent a better part of 3 hours staring at this and i can't find what's wrong with it. It's a simple recursive function to replace certain characters in a string with "_".

Function:

```
Function checkexpressionvalidity(srchstr As String) As String
Dim specialchar(0 To 7) As String
Dim revname As String
Dim pos As Integer
specialchar(0) = "\"
specialchar(1) = "/"
specialchar(2) = ":"
specialchar(3) = "*"
specialchar(4) = "?"
specialchar(5) = "<"
specialchar(6) = ">"
specialchar(7) = "|"

For i = 0 To 7
    If InStr(1, srchstr, specialchar(i), vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then
        revname = Replace(srchstr, specialchar(i), "_")
        checkexpressionvalidity = checkexpressionvalidity(revname)
    End If
Next

checkexpressionvalidity = revname
debug.print revname
End Function
```

Test Module:

```
Sub check_exp()
Dim strname As String
Dim strname2 As String
strname = "I\ am/ a / <  stupid p*erson"
strname2 = checkexpressionvalidity(strname)

End Sub
```

Debug.print results:

```
I_ am_ a _ _  stupid p_erson    '------> Clearly it works the first time.
                                         Can't figure out why it goes back
                                         and redoes it.

I_ am_ a _ _  stupid p_erson
I_ am_ a _ _  stupid p*erson

I_ am_ a _ _  stupid p_erson

I_ am_ a _ _  stupid p_erson
I_ am/ a / _  stupid p_erson

I_ am_ a _ _  stupid p_erson

I_ am_ a _ _  stupid p_erson
I_ am/ a / _  stupid p_erson
I_ am/ a / _  stupid p*erson

I_ am_ a _ _  stupid p_erson

I_ am_ a _ _  stupid p_erson
I_ am_ a _ _  stupid p*erson

I_ am_ a _ _  stupid p_erson

I_ am_ a _ _  stupid p_erson
I\ am_ a _ _  stupid p_erson

I_ am_ a _ _  stupid p_erson

I_ am_ a _ _  stupid p_erson
I\ am_ a _ _  stupid p_erson
I\ am_ a _ _  stupid p*erson

I_ am_ a _ _  stupid p_erson

I_ am_ a _ _  stupid p_erson
I_ am/ a / _  stupid p_erson

I_ am_ a _ _  stupid p_erson

I_ am_ a _ _  stupid p_erson
I\ am_ a _ _  stupid p_erson

I_ am_ a _ _  stupid p_erson

I_ am_ a _ _  stupid p_erson
I\ am_ a _ _  stupid p_erson
I\ am/ a / _  stupid p_erson

I_ am_ a _ _  stupid p_erson

I_ am_ a _ _  stupid p_erson
I_ am/ a / _  stupid p_erson

I_ am_ a _ _  stupid p_erson

I_ am_ a _ _  stupid p_erson
I\ am_ a _ _  stupid p_erson

I_ am_ a _ _  stupid p_erson

I_ am_ a _ _  stupid p_erson
I\ am_ a _ _  stupid p_erson
I\ am/ a / _  stupid p_erson
I\ am/ a / _  stupid p*erson
I\ am/ a / _  stupid p*erson
```

I am sure I am missing something really obvious.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure you even need recursion for this

Comment: Without having any idea about what this does, perhaps changing the declaration `checkexpressionvalidity(srchstr As String)` to `checkexpressionvalidity(ByVal srchstr As String)` will fix it. The default pass by reference makes recursion hard to manage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your loop is iterating over *each* character in the `specialchar` array, and the `Instr` test is operating against the `srchstr` from the initial function call, at each iteration. You *could* fix that, kind of, by doing this:

```
revname = srchstr
For i = 0 To 7
    If InStr(1, revname, specialchar(i), vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then
        revname = Replace(revname, specialchar(i), "_")
        checkexpressionvalidity = checkexpressionvalidity(revname)
    End If
Next
```

But the recursion seems unnecessary and redundant, and you'll still end up with multiple `Print` outputs, albeit they're all *correct* this time:

```
I_ am_ a _ _  stupid p_erson
I_ am_ a _ _  stupid p_erson
I_ am_ a _ _  stupid p_erson
I_ am_ a _ _  stupid p_erson
I_ am_ a _ _  stupid p_erson
I_ am_ a _ _  stupid p_erson
I_ am_ a _ _  stupid p_erson
I_ am_ a _ _  stupid p_erson
I_ am_ a _ _  stupid p_erson
I_ am_ a _ _  stupid p_erson
I_ am_ a _ _  stupid p_erson
I_ am_ a _ _  stupid p_erson
I_ am_ a _ _  stupid p_erson
I_ am_ a _ _  stupid p_erson
I_ am_ a _ _  stupid p_erson
I_ am_ a _ _  stupid p_erson
```

Doesn't this solve it without recursion?

```
Const SPECIALS = "\/:;*?<>|"

Sub check_exp()
Dim strname As String
Dim strname2 As String
strname = "I\ am/ a / <  stupid p*erson"
strname2 = CheckExp(strname)

End Sub

Function CheckExp(str$, Optional repl = "_")
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To Len(SPECIALS)
    str = Replace(str, Mid(SPECIALS, i, 1), repl)
Next
CheckExp = str
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I won't be able to check this until tomorrow but I had a couple of questions just by looking at your 2nd code (the non recursive one):
1. what's the significance of the $ sign in CheckExp(str$...) and
2. won't your str = Replace(str, Mid(SPECIALS, i, 1), repl) only work for the 1st instance of each character it finds in the string? i.e., will it replace more than one '/', "*" etc. with "_'. That's why i used recursive because i didn't think the replace function would work on all instances.

Thanks again for your detailed explanation.

Comment: `CheckExp(str$...)` the `$` is VBA short-hand notation for `As String`.

Comment: *i didn't think the replace function would work on all instances.*  But did you try it ??  :)  -- The `Replace` function has optional parameter of `Count` with default value of `-1`. If not assigned in the function call, `Replace` will replace *all* instances. The `Count` argument can be specified to restrict the number of occurences that will be replaced, by specifying any positive integer)

Answer (score 2):

As @DavidZemens, you don't need recursion to do this. However, if you ***do*** recurse it, you'll get multiple passes on identical data for 2 reasons.  You always start from the same position in the string with your `Instr` call *and* loop through all elements of the `specialchar` array.  You would need to pass one or the other as a parameter in your recursive call:

```
'Passing starting position for Instr:
Function checkexpressionvalidity(srchstr As String, Optional starting As Integer = 1) As String
    Dim specialchar() As String
    Dim revname As String
    Dim pos As Integer

    specialchar = Split("\,/,:,*,?,<,>,|", ",")

    For i = 0 To 7
        pos = InStr(starting, srchstr, specialchar(i), vbBinaryCompare)
        If pos > 0 Then
            revname = Replace(srchstr, specialchar(i), "_")
            checkexpressionvalidity = checkexpressionvalidity(revname)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    checkexpressionvalidity = revname
    Debug.Print revname
End Function
```

Output:

> ```
> I_ am_ a _ _  stupid p_erson
> I_ am_ a _ <  stupid p_erson
> I_ am_ a _ <  stupid p*erson
> I_ am/ a / <  stupid p*erson
> ```

Or:

```
'Passing index of specialchar:
Function checkexpressionvalidity(srchstr As String, Optional index As Integer = 0) As String
    Dim specialchar() As String
    Dim revname As String
    Dim pos As Integer

    specialchar = Split("\,/,:,*,?,<,>,|", ",")

    For i = index To 7
        pos = InStr(1, srchstr, specialchar(i), vbBinaryCompare)
        If pos > 0 Then
            revname = Replace(srchstr, specialchar(i), "_")
            checkexpressionvalidity = checkexpressionvalidity(revname, i + 1)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    checkexpressionvalidity = revname
    Debug.Print revname
End Function
```

Output:

> ```
> I_ am_ a _ _  stupid p_erson
> I_ am_ a _ <  stupid p_erson
> I_ am_ a _ <  stupid p*erson
> I_ am/ a / <  stupid p*erson
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Another proposal

```
Function checkexpressionvalidity(srchstr As String) As String
Dim specialchar(0 To 7) As String
Dim revname As String
Dim pos As Integer
specialchar(0) = "\"
specialchar(1) = "/"
specialchar(2) = ":"
specialchar(3) = "*"
specialchar(4) = "?"
specialchar(5) = "<"
specialchar(6) = ">"
specialchar(7) = "|"
revname = srchstr
For i = 0 To 7
    If InStr(1, srchstr, specialchar(i), vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then
        revname = Replace(revname, specialchar(i), "_")
    End If
Next

checkexpressionvalidity = revname
Debug.Print revname
End Function
```